# how can I remove XPCService by script

Tags: objective-c, macos, bash, launchd, nsxpcconnection

I create project for os x application with xpcservices that run by loginItems. that's mean the service is founded in the app in the path:{APP_NAME}.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems and who is responsible for run the service is the the main app:

```
NSXPCConnection *connection = [[NSXPCConnection alloc] initWithLoginItemName:@"{SERVICE_NAME}.app" error:&error];
```

I builded uninstaller, for deleting all the files that I installed. and I need to remove the service.
the command I used for it :

```
launchctl remove SERVICE_NAME
```

this is works fine if I run it from the terminal,
but if i run it from script it's remove the service from the "Activity Monitor" but the service still in launchctl list with status -5. 
so if I install new version its take the previous version that installed.

I run the script from xcode by `NSTask`. there is no error. it's does what the script should do. 
I  even set the administrator privileges:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e 'do shell script \"SCRIPT_NAME args 2>&1 etc\" with administrator privileges'
```

Why it's not remove like I did it in the terminal ?

p.s:
its works when run it from Xcode (even the app is in release mode)

Answer (score 0):

To remove correctly the login item you should do it in the code : 
pass  false in `SMLoginItemSetEnabled`:

```
SMLoginItemSetEnabled((__bridge CFStringRef)loginItemBundleId, false)
```